# how to show an alert message using swt?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an swt application and I want to show some alert message on any event. If user has minimized the application then also I want to show some alert at the bottom of the screen no matter what application/browser the user is looking at that time.
What is the best way to do it in swt?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832378/swt-messagebox-with-custom-button-titles) may help

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDialogs/article.html) as well.

Comment: Jface dialogs don't come up on the top if the swt application is minimized on windows. I want to show some alert even if that application is minimized and not in focus. Something like flash messages we get for google desktop mail notifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of tutorials/libraries for notifications:

- [Creating a Notification Popup Widget](http://hexapixel.com/2009/06/30/creating-a-notification-popup-widget) creates a popup notification from scratch:

  [image]
- [`Notifier` from Opal](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/Notifier) is a "ready-to-go" implementation of a notification system (including support for themes and HTML content):

  [image]

Comment: This first one as its based on swt only

Comment: @IshanRastogi Fair enough :)